# Sed and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8, ssh, sed

In SSH (Putty) I'm using a command to replace some text in a file which is encoded in UTF-8

For example

`cd ~/public_html/app/Config; sed -i 's/ADDRESS_SSH/l'adresse à été correctement intégréé/g' param.php;`

In the file all is OK but when displaying in the browser the accents are strange 
When verifing the file param.php I found that it's encoding was changing from `UTF-8` to `Europe de L'Ouest`

Same problem for .xml file too

Any help to use sed without changing the encoding or maybe to add an other ssh line for rencoding the php and xml files newly in UTF-8 ?

Best regards and thank you

Comment: The sed command has to be encoded in UTF-8. The easiest way to do this is to put the command in a file, ensuring that the file is utf-8, and then executing the file as a script.

Comment: Hello, thank you 
It will not be possible from a terminal like Putty? I'm obliged to use it

Comment: You can create, verify and run the file as described in Putty. If you instead want to issue the command directly from an interactive shell in Putty, you have to configure Putty and your shell to use UTF-8.

Comment: THak you a lot 
It was in the setting of putty and all is ok now 
Please post a reply so I will give it best answer ;)

Comment: It was on Putty configuration ==> Translation ==> Received data assumed to be in which character set ==> Choose UTF-8 Best regards

Answer (score 10):

You have to ensure that the issued `sed` command is `UTF-8` encoded.

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Write the sed command to a file, ensure the file is UTF-8, and execute it as a script:

   `file yourfile` should say `UTF-8 Unicode text`.

   You can then run `bash yourfile`.
2. Alternatively, change your terminal and shell settings to UTF-8

   `printf à | wc -c` must say 2, not 1.

   `locale` should list "UTF-8" or "utf8" in the `LC_CTYPE` line.

   You can then run the sed command straight from the terminal prompt.