# Extract data from a webpage

Tags: web-scraping, extract

I have about 10000 html downloaded files. They have a section of html code like this:

```
<tr>
   <td width="10%" valign="top"><p>City:</p></td>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        London
   </p></td>
</tr>
```

What I need is a way of getting the cities from all the files. I'm using linux so I was thinking in using some batch file to do it with sed but sed doesn't work well with these files because of some encoding issues (some cities have accents like Jérica and it wouldn't find their names).
What's the proper way of doing it?

Comment: There is not one proper way. You can do this using numerous tools and programming languages, and we would need to know at least which ones you have and are comfortable with. More on topic, it's not really clear why you couldn't find a city name. I assume you want to parse the HTML and find the part between the tags, You should be able to find that not matter the encoding. After that, you may find another solution to change the encoding of the list. I think in its current form, this question is too broad.

Comment: But if you want to try `sed` again, maybe you can have a look at [sed and UTF8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072558/sed-and-utf-8-encoding).

Comment: The problem I had is that I have a regular expression that finds (or at least I think it does) the city's name but sed would never find it. Then I discovered that saving the file with Sublime Text with utf8 made sed find the city's name, So I thought in changing all the html files encodings with iconv (which worked from iso-8859-1 to utf8) but then the accented names in the html wouldn't show  properly in firefox with the ut8 enconding. I could make a copy of all the files with the utf enconding and get the cities name but I think is overkill hence my question.

Comment: I was doing it all with linux command utils and bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the most reliable way to do this would be to use an HTML (or XML) parser.

However, if the HTML is always formatted the same way, i.e. like this:

```
<tr>
   <td width="10%" valign="top"><p>City:</p></td>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        *******
   </p></td>
</tr>
```

with the city name appearing where the asterisks are, then the following one-liner should work:

```
cat *.html |grep -A2 '<p>City' |tail -n1 |sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

Comment: Nice. But I had to add the `--text` option to grep because it was treating the html files as binary files because of the accents