# substituting a pattern with special french characters

Tags: vim, substitution

In the following text :

`la zone convective s?~@~Yetend`

I would like to replace with `sed` the characters (who are joined) `?~@~Y`by a simple quote and the "é" letter

The right french text is : la zone convective s'étend

I have tried under vim by selecting the text :

`'<,'>s/?~@~Y/\'é/g`

and

`'<,'>s/\?\~\@\~Y/\'é/g`

but none of two works.

I have also used CTRL+V and type the `'` + `é` characters from my keyboard but without success.

Anyone could have a trick to acheive this substitution under vim ?

**UPDATE 1:** I am using `vim` on a Debian 8.0 with locale below and connected by ssh from a MacOS HighSierra to this Debian :

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: What terminal and shell (and versions) are you using? Have you seen this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072558/sed-and-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen tilde with backslashes but nothing else:

```
:'<,'>s/?\~@\~Y/'é/g
```

Other characters are not special, no need to escape them. Even worse — `\?` is special so using it alone in the regexp would be an error.