# Linux Bash - modifying extracted text from stdout

Tags: bash, sed, solr, find, apache-tika

I would like to recursively scan a given directory for all `.zip` files, extract text from each such a file using Apache Tika (in my case this is `/opt/solr/bin/post` script) into a single text file and put that text file into the same directory where the original zip file is.

To find all zip files recursively and extract all the content I use:

```
find . -name "*zip" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; /opt/solr/bin/post "$f" \
-params="...params..." > "$f.txt"' \;
```

The content of the extracted file is:

```
java -classpath /opt/solr/dist/solr-core-8.7.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dout=yes -
Dparams=literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true
&extractFormat=text&defaultField=text -Dc=mycoll 
-Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool zip.zip
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/mycoll/update?
literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text
&defaultField=text...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are 
xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,
odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file zip.zip (application/octet-stream) to [base]/extract
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1614},
  "":"**EXTRACTED TEXT**",
 "null_metadata":[
    "stream_size",["79855"],
    "X-Parsed-By",["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
      "org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser"],
    "stream_content_type",["application/octet-stream"],
    "resourceName",["/mnt/remote/users/zhilov/!tmp/zip.zip"],
    "Content-Type",["application/zip"]]}
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/mycoll/update?
literal.search_area=test&extractOnly=true&
extractFormat=text&defaultField=text...
Time spent: 0:00:03.495
```

From that output I would like to cut out the beginning and the end of the file leaving only **EXTRACTED TEXT** inside of the generated file for further indexing.

Is that possible to do all those operations in one bash command line? Or at least with a bash script?

Comment: How about `sed -n '17{s/^........//;s/....$//;p;}'`?

Comment: @Beta Yes, something like this, thank you. But not literally **EXTRACTED TEXT**, just any text in that field of unknown length

Comment: Probably something between `"QTime":dd},
  "":"` and `",
 "null_metadata":[`. And if we go with `sed` I would need to settle the UTF-8 issues somehow as the text coming out after `sed` is garbled while I get that OK on the previous step

Comment: Note that `find ... -exec sh -c '...{}...'` opens you up to shell injection attacks; from a security perspective it's a very bad idea. Much safer to use `find ... -exec sh -c 'for arg in "$@"; do ...; done' _ {} +`, which passes the names of the located files in `$1`, `$2`, etc. instead of mixing the filename into a string of code (and thus risking the filename being _parsed as_ code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/QTime/{N;s/.*\n.*:.//;s/.,$//p;}'
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072558/sed-and-utf-8-encoding) addresses the UTF-8 problem.

Comment: This is very close, thank you very much. I had to add one `"` to that as I was getting wrong results, so final command became: `sed -n '/QTime/{N;s/.*\n.*:".//;s/.,$//p;}'`. The only last thing is that how can I now join all that into one line? So far I have `find . -name "*zip" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; /opt/solr/bin/post "$f" \
-params="...params..." > "$f.txt"' \;` to save the raw output to file and then I would need to find out the filename again and run your `sed` command on it

Comment: I have updated my question with the real example at the end

Comment: Ok, I have managed to do that with `sed -i` option.

Comment: You know, If I get `\nRE: Subject...` in the text all before that gets cutted

Comment: @user164863: I can't reproduce the new error.